# CSS - Convert image into the shape of a house

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have the following HTML:

```
<figure class="pimage">
  <a href="http://nathandasilva.co.uk/butlinps/property-item/schofield-road-loughborough-le11-4qj/">
    <img class="attachment-homeland_property_medium wp-post-image" width="330" height="230" alt="7-020130322113404" src="http://nathandasilva.co.uk/butlinps/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7-020130322113404-330x230.jpg"></img>
  </a>
</figure>
```

With the following CSS from what I can see:

```
.page-id-11 .pimage {
  padding: 17px !important;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

What I want to be able to do is convert the image (without distorting it) to the shape of a basic house, like the image below:-

[image]

Comment: related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444070/v-shaped-sections-of-page-with-image-background

Comment: thanks @chipChocolate.py - I'm having issues on the actual site though - you will see what I mean here; http://nathandasilva.co.uk/butlinps/

Comment: Nevermind I'll got the dimensions, I'll update my answer in a few minutes

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to put it in a jsFiddle but it is a purchased theme so it's hard to find where a lot of the elements are coming from, much appreciated @chipChocolate.py

Comment: No worries! Love to do this kinda stuff.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you noticed, but adding that has messed up the hexagon shape that sits behind

Comment: [Is this acceptable](http://s25.postimg.org/vfyraqh73/isthis.png)? Your image's `height` is not big enough to fit the whole container.

Comment: That's great @chipChocolate.py - I'll probably just move it up slightly and put some more content underneath! :D

Comment: Answer is updated with the new co-ordinates.

Comment: I've got a new issue now but I will make a new post about that, thanks again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best option is to use `svg`.

Define an inline `svg` `clipPath`([for maximum browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)) and apply it on your image.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M100,0 L200,60 L200,200 L0,200 L0,60z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200" x="0" y="0" height="200px" width="200px" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

---

### A Real Shape of House:

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0.5,0 L0.74,0.145 L0.74,0.085 L0.80.085 L0.8,0.179 L1,0.3 L0.90,0.3 L0.90,1 L0.1,1 L0.1,0.3 L0,0.3z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/300/300" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

---

### Applying same `clipPath` on different Image Sizes:

You could also apply the same `clipPath` to different image sizes.

Below is an example on 300×300, 200×200, 100×100, 50×50, 25×25, 12.5×12.5 and 5×5 image sizes.

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0.5,0 L0.74,0.145 L0.74,0.085 L0.80.085 L0.8,0.179 L1,0.3 L0.90,0.3 L0.90,1 L0.1,1 L0.1,0.3 L0,0.3z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/300/300" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>

<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/200/200" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/100/100" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>

<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/50/50" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>

<svg width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/25/25" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>

<svg width="12.5" height="12.5" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/12.5/12.5" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>

<svg width="5" height="5" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/5/5" x="0" y="0" height="1px" width="1px" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

---

To fit the image in the container on your [website](http://nathandasilva.co.uk/butlinps/), like the image below:

[image]

Change your `svg` code to following:

(**Note:** Negative margin(`margin-top: -17px`) was added because you have `padding: 17px` on `.pimage`)
(The co-ordinates were achieved by doing some simple math)

```html
<svg width="296" viewBox="0 0 1.286956522 1" height="230" style="margin-top: -17px;">
  <defs style="">
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0.6434782609,0 L1.286956522,0.166666666667 L1.286956522,1 L0,1 L0,0.166666666667z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <image y="-0.1" x="0" clip-path="url(#shape)" xlink:href="http://nathandasilva.co.uk/butlinps/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7-020130322113404-330x230.jpg" height="1px" width="1.286956522px"></image>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `pseudo elements`, example:

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    height: 230px;  /* image height */
    width: 330px;   /* image width */
}

div:before{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 175px 0 0;         /* 175px = image width/2 */
    border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
}

div:after{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 175px 100px 0;
    border-color: transparent #ffffff transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://nathandasilva.co.uk/butlinps/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7-020130322113404-330x230.jpg" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ap9nnz82/)

Comment: If you put the `img` tag inside anchor `a` tag, [see what happens](http://jsfiddle.net/ap9nnz82/1/). The triangle is unclickable.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py well, without changing the markup I doubt that's possible (for a pure CSS solution). However, if the OP is willing to change its markup then [here is a clickable example](http://jsfiddle.net/ve6b8utj/) (I edited the code given from [csshexagon.com](http://csshexagon.com/)).

Comment: could you not use jQuery to find the nearest anchor to make it clickable with this method?

Comment: @nsilva in both of my examples I don't use JQuery. You can use it and make the triangled part clickable.